# Setup doctrine command to generate only mapping file

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm new to symfony and doctrine, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

If I run the command

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

Doctrine creates an Entity with the given class name and the fields with the given types. Also it creates the mapping file.

Now what I would like is a command which creates only the mapping file.

Something like:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:mapping
```

where doctrine creates only the mapping file on the class I wrote. Is that possible, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand fully what you need to do, in any case mapping files I guess could be generated only if read from an existent database or with a conversion of the mappings:

```
(in symfony) $ php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert
```

If you would like to use doctrine command it is in:

```
$ php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine
```

But I never run this in a full stack symfony framework.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the seccond command already helps a lot. which part don't you fully understand what I try to do?